# Rounding a double to two decimal places with a placeholder

Tags: c#, rounding

I have seen plenty of questions on how to round to two decimal places using `Math.Round()`, but not when using placeholders. This is my best attempt but the program is still giving me around 14 decimal places:

```
Console.Write("\n\nPercentatge Weight: {0}% ", 
    G[ArrayCount] * 100 / RayTotal,
    Math.Round(RayTotal, 2));
```

After this runs I am getting a percentage such as `14.3256941565`.

I just want it to be `14.33`

Should add that I don't already have the value it is dependent on what the user enters.

Comment: Your syntax for the `Console.Write({0}, arg)` is off. You have two args but only have `{0}` in your write statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholder `{0}` refers to the *first* argument, but your rounded value is the *second* argument.

To format it with the placeholder only, you would need to include the `F2` specified, where `2` is the number of decimal places:

```
Console.Write("\n\nPercentatge Weight: {0:F2}% ", G[ArrayCount] * 100 / RayTotal);
```

Further info in [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks v.much!!

Answer (score 2):

If you already have your number as a percentage, you can use `f2` as a format string to round to the 2 decimal places:

```
double myDouble = 14.3256941565;
Console.WriteLine("Percentage Weight: {0:f2}%", myDouble); // Percentage Weight: 14.33%
```

Otherwise you can use `p2` as a format string to automatically format the number as a percentage:

```
double myDouble = 0.143256941565;
Console.WriteLine("Percentage Weight: {0:p2}", myDouble); // Percentage Weight: 14.33 %
```

**Further Reading**

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
   double myDouble = 14.3256941565;

   Console.WriteLine("Percentage Weight: {0}%", Math.Round(myDouble, 2));
```